# I have a bunch of different functions, and a str variable that I know is the name of one of them. How do I call that function without using ifs?

Tags: python, function, variables

Like this:

```
def f1(): ...
def f2(): ...
def f3(): ...
def f4(): ...

x = "f1"  # or "f2", "f3", or "f4"
```

Then I want to call the function that matches the value of `x`.

The only way I thought of is using a lot of `if`s but that will get inefficient very fast once I get lots of functions.

Comment: You could use `globals`, `getattr`, or a dictionary that you create, but why do you have a name of a function in the first place? Needing to call a function whose name matches a string is an odd requirement and suggests that you have things set up wrong.

Comment: I think you should rather set up one function with a parameter. The parameters value then decides what part of the function is executed.

Comment: The string is user input, I need to call different functions depending on what the user inputted.

Comment: MrIrrelevant if I do that, that means I have to do a bunch of ifs, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid because there will be quite a lot of functions. If there is no other solution, I can do that, however.

Comment: Define inefficient. Also, you may be solving the wrong problem. Other design patterns likely avoid this scenario entirely. To avoid an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info), you should probably add the concrete use case to your question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You have closed this and pointed the OP to an answer that suggests using Eval on user supplied freeform text. That is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MatBailie I have not pointed the OP to using eval. I have linked two equivalent questions. Go ahead and downvote the eval answer and upvote the answer that is identical to the one given here.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you would do this by making a dictionary that maps the string names of functions to the actual functions:

```
table = {
    "f1": f1,
    "f2": f2,
    # etc
}
```

Then you can use `x` to look up the correct function in the table and execute it:

```
table[x]()
```